# How to retrieve data from XML between tags using c#?

Tags: asp.net, xml, model-view-controller, xmlhttprequest, innertext

I'm making an HTTP call to a webservice which gives me a response in an XML format. The problem that i'm facing right now is on how to read those data which are in between the elements.

Below is my code.

```
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();

        document.Load("http://thecatapi.com/api/categories/list");

        XmlNodeList categoryNodes = document.SelectNodes("//response/data/categories");

        foreach (XmlNode categoryNode in categoryNodes)
        {
            XmlNode category = categoryNode.SelectSingleNode("category");
           var id =categoryNode.Attributes["id"].InnerXml;
           string name = categoryNode.Attributes["name"].InnerText;
        }
        document.Save("test-doc.xml");
```

Here is the structure of the XML

```
      <response>
          <data>
             <categories>
                  <category>
                      <id>5</id>
                      <name>boxes</name>
                  </category>
                  <category>
                      <id>8</id>
                      <name>boys</name>
                  </category>
              </categories>
           </data>
       </response>
```

Comment: Can you add a little structure of the xml to your question?

Comment: @Bosco Here is the structure. I forgot about this.

Answer (score 0):

try using `XElement`

```
try
{
    XElement booksFromFile = XElement.Load("http://thecatapi.com/api/categories/list");

    var category = booksFromFile.Element("data").Element("categories").Elements("category");

    foreach (var element in category)
    {
        var id = element.Element("id").Value;
        var name = element.Element("name").Value; 
    }
    booksFromFile.Save("test-doc.xml");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //handle and log the error here
}
```