# How to pull out of xml-file

Tags: c#, xml, web, get-request

Via GET-request I got next xml code:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<Translation code=\"200\"lang=\"en-ru\"><text>Sample</text></Translation>
```

So in particular I need to "stretch out" word "Sample". How?

Is this considering as deserialization?

Comment: Which programming language will you be using?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57241011/how-to-retrieve-data-from-xml-between-tags-using-c/57241964#57241964)

Answer (score 0):

Implemented with next code:

```
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;

                var json = await responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync();

                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

                doc.LoadXml(json);

                var text = doc.GetElementsByTagName("text")[0].InnerText;
            }
```

Output: Sample

Comment: `json` is an odd name for a piece of xml.

Comment: And do have a look at XElement as an alternative.